# ESLint is not recognizing global property

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm testing my React App using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) and I needed to create a new `render` function since I always need a `wrapper` around my tested components. So I decided to keep it in the `global` namespace and everything is working fine when running `jest`, but my IDE (VSCode) doesn't recognize the variable hence I have no Intellisense (that's pretty bad IMO)

`setupTests.ts`:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import "jest-styled-components";
import "./utils";
```

`utils.ts`:

```
import { render } from "./renderMock";

global.testUtils = {
    render,
};
```

`utils.d.ts`:

```
type RenderResult = import("@testing-library/react").RenderResult;
type RenderOptions = import("@testing-library/react").RenderOptions;
type Render = (
    ui: React.ReactElement,
    renderOptions?: RenderOptions
) => RenderResult;

type TestUtils = {
    render: Render;
};

declare module NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        testUtils: TestUtils;
    }
}

declare const testUtils: TestUtils;
```

`.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest/globals": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "react-app",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:jest/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2021,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "prettier", "@typescript-eslint"],
    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error", // Checks rules of Hooks
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn" // Checks effect dependencies
    }
}
```

And finally the error (in `component.test.tsx`):

```
const { render } = testUtils; // cannot find name 'testUtils'
```

Comment: `const { render } = global.testUtils` complains too?

Comment: Yes: `Property 'testUtils' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)`